# Show name of the project in the table list of event

Tags: laravel-backpack

I want to show the "Project" Name. Under the project, I have created an event, and on the listing page, I want to show the name of the project not the id of the project.

Both tables share the relationship between them.
I am using a laravel-backpack.
1)The below is the event model.

```
public function eventProject()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Project','project_id','id');
}
```

2) And the project model like this.

```
public function projectEvent()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Event', 'project_id', 'id');
}
```

how can I show in the grid list like this, 'Project name', 'Event name', etc?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help. 
You put a setColumnDetails into the setupListOperation in your crud controller.

```
$this->crud->setColumnDetails( 'project_id', [
        'label'     => "Project", // Table column heading
        'type'      => 'text',
        'name'      => 'project.project_name', // the column that contains the ID of that connected entity;
        //     'entity' => 'project', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => "project.name", // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model'     => "App\Models\Project", // foreign key model,
        'orderable' => true,

        'orderLogic'  => function ( $query, $column, $column_direction ) {
            return $query->join( 'projects', 'projects.id', '=', 'events.project_id' )
                         ->orderBy( 'project.id', 'desc' );
        },
        'searchLogic' => function ( $query, $column, $searchTerm ) {
            $query->orWhereHas( 'project', function ( $q ) use ( $column, $searchTerm ) {
                $q->where( 'projects.name', 'like', '%' . $searchTerm . '%' );
            } );
        }
    ] );
```

This basically just changes it from the id to the name field, assuming the project name is stored in the "name" field.